# Mix-blend-mode: multiply not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, mix-blend-mode

I am trying to use `mix-blend-mode: multiply` on Chrome but it doesn't work as expected: when I add `magenta`, `cyan` and `yellow` together it doesn't give me black but [brown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lBQ2.png). In Safari, everything is working fine.

[image]

I tried the trick to add the following code :

```
html, body {
    background-color: white;
}
```

But it does not change anything. Is there any other solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a somewhat known issue with `mix-blend-mode` and body, the issue is that it doesn’t take into effect the body as background, so you should try using an intermediate `div` with white background for this effect.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't change anything

Comment: can you share a snippet/fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when using `mix-blend-mode` in Google Chrome on a computer that has a DCI-P3 color gamut.

The reason that it happens has to do with color spaces. Blend mode calculations in some browsers are done in the display’s color space, which may not be sRGB, but CSS color declarations are in sRGB [(unless specified otherwise).](https://webkit.org/blog/10042/wide-gamut-color-in-css-with-display-p3)

A max-saturated CSS color such as `#ff0000` is not maximally saturated in a larger color space like DCI-P3. [colorjs.io’s converter](https://colorjs.io/apps/convert) shows that the reddest red `rgb(srgb 255 0 0)` in sRGB is equivalent to a partially saturated red `rgb(p3 235.052, 61.663, 46.740)` in P3.

On a P3 screen, multiplying magenta, cyan and yellow produces a result of multiplying these colors that’re partially saturated, and that doesn’t make black.

[This article](https://danielcwilson.com/blog/2020/03/blend-modes-in-spaaaace) explains how that works.

Image in the article:

> [image]

**Read More : https://danielcwilson.com/blog/2020/03/blend-modes-in-spaaaace**